# JavaScript library that executes scripting language in browser

Tags: javascript, browser, lua, basic

Is there some JS library that could execute script written in some other scripting language (like Lua) in a browser environment. E.g. something like this.

```
TheLibabry.executeScript(scriptCode, apiObjects, timeout);
```

I know about eval() function, but I need a script to run in isolated environment i.e. do not have access to my code. And I want some simple, classic imperative language like Lua or even basic. Also, I want to be able to set a timeout for this script. I.e. limit execution time.

Comment: Writing a compiler from scratch in JS could be a good idea. Given that you don't have to worry about memory stuff and the parsing can be delegated to Peg.js or similar, that isn't as scary as it sounds.

Comment: I am not sure I am ready to write one more compiler right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try leveraging WebAssembly to run different code languages.

> Wasm Lua

https://github.com/vvanders/wasm_lua

> Docs for web assembly

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly

> Available langs in Web Assembly

https://github.com/appcypher/awesome-wasm-langs

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/get-started-with-webassembly-using-only-14-lines-of-javascript-b37b6aaca1e4